# This path is not anchored in the source project name

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-migration-tools

I'm having trouble to migrate WI, that already have been migreted inside the organization between projetcs.
Acordding de debug, the sistem is gatting informations from area path and interacion path from when the WI has been created, no from it's atual stauts.

Error:

ERR] System.InvalidOperationException: This path is not anchored in the source project name: OldTeamProjet\Iteraction1\iteraction2
at MigrationTools.Enrichers.TfsNodeStructure.GetNewNodeName(String sourceNodePath, TfsNodeStructureType nodeStructureType) in D:\a\1\s\src\MigrationTools.Clients.AzureDevops.ObjectModel\ProcessorEnrichers\TfsNodeStructure.cs:line 99
at VstsSyncMigrator.Engine.WorkItemMigrationContext.PopulateWorkItem(WorkItemData oldWi, WorkItemData newwit, String destType) in D:\a\1\s\src\VstsSyncMigrator.Core\Execution\MigrationContext\WorkItemMigrationContext.cs:line 383
at VstsSyncMigrator.Engine.WorkItemMigrationContext.ReplayRevisions(List`1 revisionsToMigrate, WorkItemData sourceWorkItem, WorkItemData targetWorkItem) in D:\a\1\s\src\VstsSyncMigrator.Core\Execution\MigrationContext\WorkItemMigrationContext.cs:line 617

the area path should be is SoucerProject/IteractionA

the same is happening in the Iteraction path, is getting a path from creation.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to setup AreaMaps and IterationMaps processor

```
Processors: [{
    "AreaMaps": {
        "Unknown Area": "Desired Area"
    },
    "IterationMaps": {
        "Unknown Iteration in Source": "Desired Iteration"
    }
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this because you have the `ReplayRevisions` set to true, and it is replaying all the revisions (including assignments to Area Paths and Iteration Paths)?

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](https://nkdagility.com/learn/azure-devops-migration-tools/Reference/v1/Processors/WorkItemMigrationContext/), you need to add [Iteration Maps and Area Maps](https://nkdagility.com/learn/azure-devops-migration-tools/Reference/v1/Processors/WorkItemMigrationContext/#iteration-maps-and-area-maps) that adapt the old locations to new ones that are valid in the Target.

Before your migration starts it will validate that all of the Areas and Iterations from the **Source** work items revisions exist on the **Target**. Any that do not exist will be flagged in the logs and if you have `"StopMigrationOnMissingAreaIterationNodes": true,` set the migration will stop just after it outputs a list of the missing nodes.

Our algorithm that converts the Source nodes to Target nodes processes the [mappings](https://nkdagility.com/learn/azure-devops-migration-tools/Reference/v1/Processors/WorkItemMigrationContext/#iteration-maps-and-area-maps) at that time. This means that any valid mapped nodes will never be caught by the `This path is not anchored in the source project` message as they are already altered to be valid.

> We recently updated the logging for this part of the system to more easily debug both your mappings and to see what they system is doing with the nodes and their current state. You can set `"LogLevel": "Debug"` to see the details.

To add a mapping, you can follow [the documentation](https://nkdagility.com/learn/azure-devops-migration-tools/Reference/v1/Processors/WorkItemMigrationContext/#iteration-maps-and-area-maps) with this being the simplest way:

```
"IterationMaps": {
  "WorkItemMovedFromProjectName\\\\Iteration 1": "TargetProject\\Sprint 1",
},
"AreaMaps": {
   "WorkItemMovedFromProjectName\\\\Team 2": "TargetProject\\ProductA\\Team 2",
}
```

Or you can use regular expressions to match the missing area or iteration paths:

```
"IterationMaps": {
  "^OriginalProject\\\\Path1(?=\\\\Sprint 2022)": "TargetProject\\AnotherPath\\NewTeam",
  "^OriginalProject\\\\Path1(?=\\\\Sprint 2020)": "TargetProject\\AnotherPath\\Archives\\Sprints 2020",
  "^OriginalProject\\\\Path2": "TargetProject\\YetAnotherPath\\Path2",
},
"AreaMaps": {
  "^OriginalProject\\\\(DescopeThis|DescopeThat)": "TargetProject\\Archive\\Descoped\\",
  "^OriginalProject\\\\(?!DescopeThis|DescopeThat)": "TargetProject\\NewArea\\",
}
```

Regular expressions are much more difficult to build and debug so it is a good idea to use a [regular expression tester](https://regex101.com/) to check that you are matching the right things.

*NOTE: You need `\\` to escape a `\` the pattern, and `\\` to escape a `\` in JSON. Therefor on the left of the match you need 4 `\` to represent the `\\` for the pattern and only 2 `\` in the match*

[image]

[You can find this discussed on the Azure DevOps Migration Project](https://github.com/nkdAgility/azure-devops-migration-tools/discussions/1680)